# Force marker into nearest road google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, marker

I'm developing an app that tracks the GPS position of the user and shows it with a marker in the map. The updates are every 2 seconds.

The problem is the position I get is not so accurate than with other apps like WAZE, Maps, and so on. The user always is driving so is in the road, but the marker sometimes is about few meters left or right out.

Using the other apps this is not happening, like they know that you are in a road and snaps the position to it ignoring a little GPS error.

- No destination position
- "Free mode"
- Move marker to nearest road

I need a local solution without any request to Directions or Routes API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no local solution as google does not expose map data to you without using one of their api's

Answer (score 0):

To get the most accurate location use GPS_PROVIDER

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, getApplicationContext());
```

And in onLocationChanged(), check for the accuracy of the received Location, if it is accurate enough for you then do your task otherwise ignore it.

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float accuracy=arg0.getAccuracy();
        if(accuracy<10){//set your desired accuracy , lesser the value the more accurate it is
            //do your tasks
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location not accurate enough ("+accuracy+")" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```